# angular text input adds values to repeated text inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

I have a series of comment inputs that repeat.  When I start typing in one, all inputs are populated with the characters I am typing.

How do I have the text input value only populate in the text input I am typing into?

Here is what my template looks like:

```
<li ng-repeat="post in feed.posts" class="media media-clearfix-xs">
<form ng-submit="feed.addComment(post.id, post.comment_set)">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input ng-model="feed.desc" type="text" class="form-control" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
         <button ng-click="submit()" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i></button>
        </span>
</div>
</form> 
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have that `desc` property on `post` level instead of directly putting inside controller context `feed`(assuming `feed` is controller alias)

```
<input ng-model="post.desc" type="text" class="form-control" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It should not , since you have a array  where each object which deals with each line, change ng-model to be `post.desc` not `feed.desc`

```
<input ng-model="post.desc" type="text" class="form-control" />
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/7MhLd/2225/)